# How to switch from a Frame in a website using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to switch from a frame?

I am able switch to the frame.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);

WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body"));

frame.sendKeys("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"myTab\"]/li[3]/a/span[2]/span")).click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```